# Find sheets row with two matching column values in Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I'm creating a zap and using the "Lookup Spreadsheet Row"

I'm looking for two matching values within a row, if one column value matches "A" and another column in the same row's value is "B" then I want to use that row ID to continue.

Is there a way to lookup a row with two matching values in separate columns?

I can't seem to find any help documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

We can only search one column at a time for simplicity's sake. The best solution here is to create a composite column in your spreadsheet. Then in Zapier, you can search for that combination. Here's a simple example:

[image]

In your zap setup, you can build your search string from previous fields:

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense!